# python something like assertFunctionNotCalled?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Edit: This question refers to python 3.5

In python unit testing, is there a way to assert that a given block of code is not called?

I have a function I am testing that can follow either of two branches: a faster, more reliable branch if the user has logged in before, or a slower less reliable branch if this is their first visit. Basically, the first time a user logs in, the program has to request information about them from separate server, which can be slow (and, occasionally, down). Once it has the information, however, it caches it locally and should just use the local cache for the data on subsequent logins.

The end result of the function is the same either way, so there is no way for me to know which code branch it took to get the information by simply looking at the output of the function. So ideally I'd like to be able to do effectively an `assertFunctionNotCalled` to test that it is pulling from the local cache on the second (and subsequent) login attempt. How should I best test this?

Comment: Are you mocking out the separate server for these tests? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: no, I do the actual request. Since it is just a SELECT, it doesn't hurt it to be run many times.

Comment: It might not hurt anything, but does make it more difficult to test (and to tell which side any breaking changes happened). Perhaps this should be a unit test against a mock, and the tests that actually call out should be separate integration tests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That makes sense. And with that function being a mock, I can then directly check if it was called (or is that what MagicMock is needed for?). Just check that the function works as desired completely separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bool called like so:

```
from mock import patch
with patch('something') as mock_something:
    self.assertFalse(mock_something.called)
```